# Search solr docs by search term with sort by distance

Tags: java, search, elasticsearch, solr

**My use case**

I am writing code to show nearby shops with search functionality. I want to fetch shops from solr as per given use case - if I search for term : "allen so", all nearby shops start with term "allen so" should come first. And nearest shop should come up.*

**Existing query**

```
{ 
  q: 'allen so*',
  defType: 'edismax',
  pt: '28.4836556,77.1074802',
  qf: 'shop_name^4 cat^3 sub_cat^2',
  fl: '*,distance:geodist()',
  start: '0',
  sort: 'geodist() asc',
  rows: '20',
  sfield: 'shop_loc',
  wt: 'json' 
}
```

By hitting above query I am not getting relevant result.

Doc structure :

```
{
    "shop_id": "1",
    "shop_name": "Allen Solly",
    "shop_nickname": "Allen Solly",
    "shop_summary": "A search of the AAAC archives yields little about Allen Solly suits except the fact that they were sold about fifty years ago. These days they appear to be mainly a woman's brand, mainly focussed only on casual or business casual clothes, and mainly popular in India. Yet the label says \"Established 1744 / Nottingham, England.\"",
    "shop_description": "A search of the AAAC archives yields little about Allen Solly suits except the fact that they were sold about fifty years ago. These days they appear to be mainly a woman's brand, mainly focussed only on casual or business casual clothes, and mainly popular in India. Yet the label says \"Established 1744 / Nottingham, England.\"",
    "shop_address_1": "MGF Metropolitan Mall, MG Rd, Heritage City, Sector 25, Gurugram, Haryana 122002",
    "shop_address_2": "Gurgaon, Haryana, India",
    "shop_city": "Gurgaon",
    "shop_state": "Haryana",
    "shop_country": "India",
    "shop_area_code": "122002",
    "shop_opening_time": "11:00:00",
    "shop_closing_time": "19:00:00",
    "shop_working_days": "Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday",
    "currency": "INR",
    "active": true,
    "user_id": "4",
    "created_at": "2016-11-29T10:07:17Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-11-29T10:07:20Z",
    "cat": [
      "Clothing & Accessories"
    ],
    "sub_cat": [
      "mens casual shirts",
      "mens sweater"
    ],
    "shop_loc": "28.480853965280254,77.08022397011518"
}
```

Please help me out, I am stuck badly!!

Answer (score 0):

For spatial queries you have to use spatial filters to get correct result.If you want distance as document score then q parameter needs to have {!func}geodist(). Otherwise you can alternatively use geofilt parser in fq.

For more info refer here:https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spatial+Search

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if i pass {!func}geodist() in query, then where the search term will go ?

Comment: From the top of my mind  q=_val_:mynumericfield _val_:"recip(rord(myfield),1,2,3)" Refer here for more multiple  query in q pram. https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax